# IntelliJ : Deploy app on Tomcat. AUTHORIZATION issues

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

have been developing a java app being compiling and built with Maven.
Trying to deploy it on tomcat server.

to deploy I added the next plugin-section to pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <server>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</server>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <path>/rps</path>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and also had had before the section

```
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

and it is able to deploy my  "testapp" onto tomcat server with
command line:

**$ mvn install tomcat7:deploy**

- in this case everything will be ok

BUT from IntelliJ my tries are unsuccessful. I have the next failure:

> [INFO] --- **tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy** (default-cli) @ testapp
> --- [INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/rps   Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Frps Uploaded:
> http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Frps (11 KB at 1053.5
> KB/sec)
>
> Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Frps
> Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Frps (11 KB
> at 2107.0 KB/sec)
>
> tomcatManager status code:401, ReasonPhrase: [INFO]  [INFO]  [INFO]  
> [INFO]   401 **Unauthorized** [INFO]  <etc..> [INFO]
>
> [INFO]
>
> ## 401 Unauthorized
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO]    
> **You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed [INFO]     any configuration files, please examine the file [INFO]    
> conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That [INFO]    
> file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp. [INFO]  
> For example, to add the manager-gui role to a user named
> [INFO]     tomcat with a password of s3cret, add the
> following to the [INFO]     config file listed above.**

Everything is clear but have no idea **where in IntelliJ I can assign admin-user name and password in order to get access to tomcat**?
Obviously, I have admin-user-role credentials entries in **maven/settings.xml** :

```
<server>
     <id>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

and correspondingly in **tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml** have:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-gui"/>
```

PS To run it this way I changed run configuration to execute command like with it was
with command line: **install tomcat7:deploy -f pom.xml**

in case when I try to configure a new run-configuration based on TomCat Server there will happen much more serious and unpredictable problems which should as i think be described in a separate question.

Couldn't imagine it would be such a tremendous problem to deploy an existing app on tomcat)
There are on youtube a video from JetBrain how to do that but without any connection
to developing within Maven-framework concept.

TYA
Sergei

Comment: Try to define the credentials of your tomcat in the .m2/settings.xml or conf/senttings.xml of your maven

Comment: thank you, but actually as it mentioned in my questions, i have these credentials added to these files (actually, settings.xml is placed in maven-home-folder like /opt/maven or Program Files\maven etc. in Windows, isn't it)